# VTK: The data array in the element may be too short

Tags: data-visualization, vtk

I'm trying to visualize some data in vtr format. For this purposes I've created a couple **npy** files by [this library](https://github.com/rogersce/cnpy), then I've converted this files by [PyEVTK](https://bitbucket.org/pauloh/pyevtk) into the vtr format (like in the `lowlevel.py` example). But when I'm trying to visualize this data by ParaView, an error appears:

```
ERROR: In /var/tmp/portage/sci-visualization/paraview-4.0.1-r1/work/ParaView-v4.0.1-source/VTK/IO/XML/vtkXMLDataReader.cxx, line 510
vtkXMLRectilinearGridReader (0x36bb080): Cannot read point data array "Pressure" from PointData in piece 0.  The data array in the element may be too short.
```

Can anybody explain, what exactly means this error message, and what's wrong with the my visualization data?

**Solved**:

I made a stupid mistake - data size in header was different from the actual data size, and this was the cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

This error may be coming from the XML header declaration, that may not contain all data needed. You may miss the `header_type` that contains the size of each info written between each set of data.

```
<VTKFile type="UnstructuredGrid" version="0.1" byte_order="BigEndian" header_type="UInt64">
```

Comment: I found the mistake some time ago, but I forgot update the question (the 'Solved' section). Anyway - thanks, your answer is close enough.